# Expose child interface methods in c#

Tags: c#, oop

We have a Manager class which exposes a property of type IDevice,

```
public interface IDevice {
    string GetId();
}

public class Manager{

    public IDevice Device
    {
     get;
    }

}
```

Now I have a new interface which extends from IDevice,

```
public interface IBleDevice : IDevice{
   string GetBleId();
}
```

Is there a way  by which can we expose the methods of IBleDevice to consumer of the class with the same parent reference (IDevice) without casting??

Eg:

```
void main(){
  new Manager().Device.GetBleId(); // which requires casting now
}
```

Comment: Any chances that `Manager` 's `Device` property can be type of `IBleDevice` ? as `IBleDevice` is implementing `IDevice` I don't think you may face any functionality problem in that.

Comment: What is your actual use case? There are ways but they won't work with `new Manager().Device.GetBleId()` but, since that snippet doesn't make a lot of sense anyway, you may be able to leverage them

Comment: Why would you expect this to work?  The property is an IDevice, you are trying to access something that is off of IBleDevice

Comment: If you want this to work you'll need to change the language you're using. C# is a statically-typed language. In other words, you need to know your types at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

How about use Generic method.

```
public interface IDevice
{
    string GetId();
}

public class Manager
{

    public TResult GetDevice<TResult>() 
        where TResult : IDevice
    {
        return (TResult)Device;
    }

    public IDevice Device
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface IBleDevice : IDevice
{
    string GetBleId();
}
```

You can use like this.

```
new Manager().GetDevice<IBleDevice>().GetBleId(); // which requires casting now
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, The problem is that the consumer will never know what kind device it is. Is there a way we can say some thing like where T : IDevice or IBleDevice  without expecting the user to know much about it ?

Comment: Exactly this is the solution which I wanted to say, Thank you @D-Shish

Comment: @user170940 - If the user doesn't know what to expect the user can always use IDevice.If that is not enough, the Manager could be made generic (if a manager always manages one type of devices)

Comment: @user170940: If you do not want to mention your sub-interface (IBleDevice ) in usage place I think you can use "dynamic" type in your manager class for Device propery. "public dynamic Device" then consumer can write new Manager().GetDevice<IBleDevice>().GetBleId(); and you will not have compile time error and also in runtime GetBleId would execute

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh OP said the consumer wouldn’t know the type, your example has the type declared which is the exact opposite of what the OP wants.

Comment: @maccettura: When you do not know the type in runtime and you want to write your code and mention to the unknown type members without any compile error the only way is "Invoke" or "dynamic" and I believe dynamic will work in this case

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh you skipped over the point of my comment competently. Your answer still declares the type in the generic function. OP literally just said they can’t do that

Comment: @maccettura: I did a mistake in my codes and I've used the wrong usage sample, Now I've edited my answer with correct one sir

Answer (score -2):

As you said if the consumer is not aware of `IBleDevice`, You can use "dynamic" type in your manager class for Device property. Like this:

```
public dynamic Device
    {
     get;
    }
```

Then the consumer can write

```
 new Manager().Device.GetBleId();
```

And you will not get any compile error and also in runtime `GetBleId` will execute

Comment: You're mixing code from the OP's question and from D-Shih's answer.

Comment: Ok now after edit your code throws a run time exception when Device is IDevice

Comment: @maccettura, Yes definitely if Device being IDevice this code will throw an exception, But OP did not mention this, He wants to use an unknown type member without casting and this is the solution

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh this is not the solution when it breaks for 50% of the OPs requirement

Comment: @maccettura, I think all the requirement was that! anyway I suppose my answer was not deserve 3 down votes :)))))

Comment: @maccettura - It's best not to delete comments.

Comment: @Enigmativity Mohammad corrected the items I pointed out, my earlier comment was obsolete. I left my other comments because they are relevant to Mohammad’s present issues

Comment: @maccettura Thanks

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh you corrected the earlier problems. Your answer is still incorrect.

Comment: @maccettura I said thanks for your comments and contemplation

Comment: @maccettura - Generally, though, even if the comment is obsolete you shouldn't delete it. It's better to be in the habit of retaining the comment than to delete it as there are many times that this removes context and makes the comments very hard to understand.

Comment: @MohammadNikravesh my mistake. No need to thank me. We’re all here to learn/teach and make each other better.